# Using multiple loader services in one ts file

Tags: angular

Good morning. I am trying to get a select box to display a list of companies along side my file array. It will eventually be used to filter the array by company.

I feel like I have what should work but it now just shows a blank page with the menu bar...

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Datafile, DatafileLoader } from '../datafile-loader.service';
import { Company, CompanyLoader } from '../../company/company-loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datafile-list',
  templateUrl: './datafile-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datafile-list.component.scss']
})
export class DatafileListComponent {
  list: Observable<Datafile[]>;
  listC: Observable<Company[]>;

  constructor(loader: DatafileLoader, loaderc: CompanyLoader) {
    this.list = loader.getList();
    this.listC = loaderc.getList();
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-card class="dashboard-card">
  <mat-card-header [style.backgroundColor]="'orange'">
    <mat-card-title>Datafiles</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content [ngStyle]="{'height':'500px', 'overflow-y': 'auto', 'background-color': 'white'}" >
      <div *ngFor="let l of list | async">
          <p style="line-height:1">
            <span> <img src="{{l.layoutPreDefined == false ? '../../../assets/images/newlayout.jpg' : '../../../assets/images/predefinedlayout.jpg'}}"/></span><br />
            <span style="font-size:12pt"> <a [routerLink]="l.id"> {{ l.fileName }} </a> </span><br />
            <span style="font-size:12pt"> {{ l.companyAbbreviation}}  &nbsp;&nbsp;  {{ l.fileTypeName }}</span><br />
            <img src="../../../assets/images/divider.jpg">
          </p>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>


<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of listC | async" [value]="c">{{c.companyAbbreviation}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Company Loader

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const apiUrl = 'http://xxxxxx/DRMSAPI-dev/API/company';

export interface Company {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  companyAbbreviation: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class CompanyLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getList(): Observable<Company[]> {
    return this.http.get<Company[]>(apiUrl).pipe(map(longList => longList.slice(0, 9)), tap(results => console.log(results)));
  }

  getDetails(id: string): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.get<Company>(
      `${apiUrl}/${id}`
    );
  }
}
```

datafile module

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DatafileDetailComponent } from './datafile-detail/datafile-detail.component';
import { DatafileListComponent } from './datafile-list/datafile-list.component';

import { DatafileLoader } from './datafile-loader.service';

import { EDXMaterialModule } from '../shared/edxMaterialModule';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { CompanyLoader } from '../company/company-loader.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DatafileListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: DatafileDetailComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DatafileListComponent, DatafileDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    EDXMaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [DatafileLoader, CompanyLoader]
})
export class DatafileModule { }
```

I added the CompanyLoader to the providers in the datafile.module and now I am seeing the selector and the card but they are both blank...sigh...

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: also this should be changed `*ngFor="let c of listC | async"`

Comment: No errors in the console and I added | async (updated the post with the change), but no difference.

Comment: so you don't see either cards or the select, correct? (may be it's better to create a stackblitz)

Comment: I now have the datafile array showing in the card but still just a blank selector. Stakblitz is not allowing me to upload my files into a new project. Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how its your service but if you need connect to an Api, you need to use an Observable to get your data.

You can see it in the following link

https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

Sorry, I need see your service to answer you.

Comment: I added the company loader, which does work as is on a separate page.